# How to get the value of the selected Item in a Drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I have a drop down list populated from a database. When i use the dplTags.SelectedItem.Value it **only returns the first value and not the one i selected?**

Could Someone tel me where i'm going wrong?

When i call it:

```
String TagID = dplTags.SelectedItem.Value; // Will only select the first value????
```

It always returns the TagID of the first item, not the selected one :\

This is how i bind it:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter daTags
                = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Tag", conn);

                DataSet dsTags = new DataSet("TagCloud");

                daTags.FillSchema(dsTags, SchemaType.Source, "Tag");
                daTags.Fill(dsTags, "Tag");

                daTags.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
                daTags.Fill(dsTags, "Tag");

                DataTable tblTag;
                tblTag = dsTags.Tables["Tag"];

                dplTags.DataSource = dsTags;
                dplTags.DataMember = "Tag"; 
                dplTags.DataValueField = "TagID"; //Value Member
                dplTags.DataTextField = "Value"; // Display Member
                dplTags.DataBind();
            }
```

Please help, Thanks in Advance.

Comment: try DropDownList.SelectedItem.Value.ToString(), it works for me. Also try to debug the code to check the actual SelectedValue of the DropDownList item.

Comment: Tryed that the .ToString() made no diffrence. even if i select item 5 and in the dropdownlist it shows the value of the 5th item, but when i click the submit button, and check my code with bullet points the .selecteditem is always the first one.

Comment: Adil's solution may serve your purpose. Try that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you binding data to these dropdown list controls? They should be bound only in the initial loading of the page as follows. I suspect that you are binding them in every page load and therefore selected values disappear.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        //Please check if you are binding checkbox controls here. 
        //If not bring them in here
    }
}
```

Comment: No just in the one page_load, i only have one page

Answer (score 1):

keep viewstate of page enabled and databind the dropdown only when Page.IsPostback == false

Answer (score 1):

Bind the dropdown list once on first page load and do not bind it again on postback. Binding it again will fill the dropdown with new elements and previous selection will be lost.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter daTags
                = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Tag", conn);

                DataSet dsTags = new DataSet("TagCloud");

                daTags.FillSchema(dsTags, SchemaType.Source, "Tag");
                daTags.Fill(dsTags, "Tag");

                daTags.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
                daTags.Fill(dsTags, "Tag");

                DataTable tblTag;
                tblTag = dsTags.Tables["Tag"];

                dplTags.DataSource = dsTags;
                dplTags.DataMember = "Tag"; 
                dplTags.DataValueField = "TagID"; //Value Member
                dplTags.DataTextField = "Value"; // Display Member
                dplTags.DataBind();
            }
}
```